# How to display large content in div using js and html without any library

Tags: javascript, html

I have large JSON data that I need to display in my webpage. When I display it directly, the tab freezes for some time and clicks won't work 10 seconds.

```
<div>
/* json content goes here */
</div>
```

I would like to fix this problem without using any external library with just HTML and js. For simulation, you can use any data that's at least 5MB.

Comment: Does it still display the content after those 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, it freezes for 10 seconds and displays the data.

Comment: That is a gigantic request so it's likely just the size that's the problem. Consider splitting the data into different pages and making individual requests on each page.

Comment: It's not the API that's the issue, I'll need to render the whole JSON in one page without splitting into multiple pages. I am trying to build a json viewer in my webpage. I've tried using different elements. couldn't find anything that helped.

Comment: If you're loading that much data onto one page without a framework there's not much else you can do. Either find a workaround or accept the delay.

Comment: How about lazyloading without any libraries?

Comment: Never tried it but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Something like this could be good: https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload

Comment: also to keep it from freezing you could use requestAnimationFrame and create a recursive function that appended the content every frame, that way it doesn't freeze. It will still take 10+ seconds to render the whole thing but you will at least be able to start reading/scrolling

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able render the object asynchronously. I don't have a super large object, but this is how I would start out.

```js
let obj = {'l11': 
  {'l21':
   {
    'l31': {'l41': 'foo'},
    'l32': {'l42': 'bar'}
   },
   'l22':
   {
    'l33': {'l43': 'baz'},
    'l34': {'l44': 'lorem'},
   }
  },
  'l12': 'HATS'
};


async function handleBigObject(o)
{
  const outp = document.getElementById('object_show');
  await renderObject(o, 0, outp);
}

function renderObject(o, level, container)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => 
  {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(async key =>
    {
      let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      let lbl = document.createElement('span');
      newDiv.appendChild(lbl);
      container.appendChild(newDiv);
      lbl.textContent = key;
      if(typeof(o[key]) === 'object')
      {
        renderObject(o[key], level+1, newDiv);
      }
      else
      {
        let value = document.createElement('span');
        value.innerHTML = ' &rarr; ' + o[key];
        newDiv.appendChild(value);
      }
      lbl.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:' + (level * 10) + 'px');
    });
  });
}
      
handleBigObject(obj);
```

```css
span
{
  font-family:'lucida console',unifont;
}
```

```html
<div id="object_show"></div>
```

Comment: Also slap all that in a <pre><code></code></pre> and you should get some decent looking code.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it from freezing you could use requestAnimationFrame and create a recursive function that appended the content every frame, that way it doesn't freeze. It will still take 10+ seconds to render the whole thing but you will at least be able to start reading/scrolling

Here is an example

```
var longText = function (txt) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    if (!txt.length) return 
    window.document.getElementById('code').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', txt.substr(0, Math.min(1000, txt.length) ))
    longText(txt.substr(1000, txt.length))
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/ecatonxg/14/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your responses. I took in your ideas and was able to build a lazyloading div. Take a look. Since I am building a JSON viewer, I am going with lines to render each time and `pre` to display the formatting properly.

```
const text = JSON.stringify(checks, null, 4)
const lines = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
pre.onscroll = ()=>{
   if(pre.scrollTop + pre.clientHeight === pre.scrollHeight){
      console.info('reached the end');
      someFn();
   }
};
const displayLines = () => {
    if(lines.length>0){
      const upperLimit = lines.length >= 200 ? 200 : lines.length;
      pre.innerHTML += lines.splice(0,upperLimit).join('\n');
    } else{
      pre.innerHTML = text;
    }
 }
displayLines();
```

The code is crude but you get the gist of it. I am rendering 200 lines at a time and every time the user reaches the bottom of the div, I am rendering 200 more lines. Again, Thank you for your help.